# Embed Instagram feeds without access token

Tags: php, instagram

And yet another question!!

When people register on the site, I have a field to allow them to enter their Instagram username. I had the following code to allow users to display the last item shared in Instagram on the site, but this stopped working.

```
function scrape_insta($username) {
    $insta_source = file_get_contents('http://instagram.com/'.$username);
    $shards = explode('window._sharedData = ', $insta_source);
    $insta_json = explode(';</script>', $shards[1]); 
    $insta_array = json_decode($insta_json[0], TRUE);
    return $insta_array;
}

//Supply a username
$my_account = $instagram;
//Do the deed
$results_array = scrape_insta($my_account);
//An example of where to go from there
$latest_array = $results_array['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['user']['media']['nodes'][0];
echo '<b>Latest Photo:<br/>';
echo '<a href="http://instagram.com/p/'.$latest_array['code'].'" target=_blank><img src="'.$latest_array['display_src'].'" width=480 height=270></a></br>';
echo 'Likes: '.$latest_array['likes']['count'].' - Comments: '.$latest_array['comments']['count'].'</b><br/>';
```

I would like to be able to do this without forcing the user to get an access token, if possible. Any help is appreciated.